# Run custom javascript code after loading any website

Tags: javascript, android, html, performance, w3c

I am working on taking readings about web browser performance and so need to access the  `window.performance` object of the browser. 
To collect this data i have written a javascript file, collect.js which i need to add to the DOM of the page that i need to test eg. www.google.com, www.facebook.com and so on...

Also i need to run this test for about 1000 websites, any manual approach is out of the question. I need it to be automated somehow.

How could i go about doing this?

EDIT: I need to run these tests on an android browser, so i need mobile oriented solutions.

Comment: If you use Firefox you can use Greasemonkey.

Comment: Canoo web test and greasemonkey perhaps? there is a grease monkey for IE too

Comment: I need it to run on android, since i have to collect data of the android browser implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple android app with a `WebView` component. This way you can control which `URL`s are loaded and also insert your JS code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

**EDIT**
You can run any javascript like this:

Implement a custom `WebView`:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {       
        // Execute your javascript below
        view.loadUrl("javascript:...");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an automated solution, try [PhantomJs](http://www.phantomjs.org/) this provides an automated headless web browser. Also has access to [network traffic](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Network_traffic)

Comment: Sorry - I did not see the android tag

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try "bookmarklet"
http://www.bookmarklets.com/

the advantage over greasemonkey script is that it can run on 
firefox and explorer