# How to share html content from a webview?

Tags: java, android

Please tell me how to share the Contents of webview. I have used **myjavascriptinterface** class for registering, but I don't where the contents of webview is stored. please guide properly so that i can understand properly the usage my javascriptinterface class.

Comment: What do you mean by share?  You wanting to send the HTML to another activity in your app?  Send an image representation of the webview via text message?  Other?

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you mean with Contents HTML code i suggest you using Jsoup library it is very easy syntax:

```
Document document = JSoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
```

when you call this: String html = document.getHtml(); it returns a string of the html of the document.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what specifically you'd like to share. Here is common considerations.

In most simple case you can share just an URL. You can get it via `webview.getUrl()` method.

If you want to share a document as a whole, then next question is between what devices would you like to share them. If it's all about Android, then you can use `webview.saveWebArchive()` method to get a single XML-file ready to be sent to another Android device (the file contains the document contents with all resources).

If you want to share the document on an arbitrary platform, you could possibly access html-code yourself. For example, define a method `captureWebDocument(text)` in your Java interface, registered for JavaScript extension in the webview. Then subclass `WebViewClient` and override `onPageFinished()` method - an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634409/run-custom-javascript-code-after-loading-any-website).

In the method you should execute:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:injectedJS.captureWebDocument(document.documentElement.innerHTML)");
```

So, you'll get the document contents in your Java class, and can proceed with sharing it in any suitable way. Extracting any included resources such as images will require more coding.

Another possibility would be performing all sharing functionality (including an upload of the data to a server, if required) in the injected JavaScript.